# How to store list of values using hashmap? using following format

Tags: java

How to do Hashmap i have list of value like

```
{"tname":"Learning Ratio and Proportion Concepts and practice assessment","gname":"Sixth grade"},
{"tname":"Number System","gname":"Sixth grade"},
{"tname":"quations and expression","gname":"Seventh grade"},{"tname":"Geometry","gname":"Seventh grade"}
```

i want to store as

```
list<String>={"Sixth grade","Seventh grade"}

list(list<String>)={{"Learning Ratio and Proportion Concepts and practice assessment","Number System"},{"quations and expression","Geometry"}}
```

can any one help me thanks...

Comment: the key values can only appear *once* in a map. you have used tname and gname more than once. do you want 3 maps or 1 map?

Comment: then tname and gname can only appear once as keys in the map.

Comment: It sounds like you have a list of pairs, perhaps an object could hold the tame and gname as values. A list of objects would then have the tname gname values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to store the books needed per grade.

```
  enum Grades
  {
    SIXTH_GRADE, SEVENTH_GRADE;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Map<Grades, List<String>> literature = new HashMap<Grades, List<String>>();
    literature.put(Grades.SIXTH_GRADE, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Learning Ratio and Proportion Concepts and practice assessment","Number System")));
    literature.put(Grades.SEVENTH_GRADE, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Equations and expression","Geometry")));

    // get books for 6th grade
    List<String> books6th = literature.get(Grades.SIXTH_GRADE);

    for (String book : books6th)
      System.out.println(book);

    // get books for 7th grade
    List<String> books7th = literature.get(Grades.SEVENTH_GRADE);

    Collection<List<String>> allBooks = literature.values(); // tname data
    Set<Grades> allGrades = literature.keySet(); // data associated with gname
  }
```

I even would consider creating a `class Book` with members like ISBN number, price etc. But that depends on your use case.

I used enums here, instead of strings, so the map is less error prone. E. g. if someone accidentially writes `"6th grade"` instead of `"sixth grade"`, of course you also could use string constants.

With enums you can use an `EnumMap` instead of a `HashMap` like

`Map<Grades, List<String>> literature = new EnumMap<Grades,  List<String>>(Grades.class);`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList with HashMap

```
   HashMap<String,ArrayList<String[]>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String[]>>();

   ArrayList<String[]> theList1 = new ArrayList()<String[]>();

   theList1.add(new String[] {"Learning Ratio and Proportion Concepts and practice assessment","Sixth grade"});

   map.put("tname", theList1);
```

Comment: I'm getting error like Incorrect number of arguments for type HashMap<K,V>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <ArrayList<String[]>>

Comment: HashMap takes 2 params, you only put one. E.g.: HashMap<String, ArrayList<String[]>>

Comment: Change HashMap<String,ArrayList<String[]>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String[]>>; to  HashMap<String,ArrayList<String[]>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String[]>>();

Comment: Hmm, my commented apparently got deleted... Yes, I read the question. But there is not much to read. OP doesn't describe what he is trying to achieve. He just wants his code fixed. I am assuming that there is no need for List of String array.